# Error making components with Angular cli 1.4.3

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a project that is initially using Angular cli version: 1.0.4

I create a new component by using:

```
ng g c component1 --flat
```

And this registers fine in app.module.ts:

```
import { Component1Component } from './component1.component';
```

But I then have upgraded the project to Angular cli version: 1.4.3.

I then try making a second component by using:

```
ng g c component2 --flat
```

It creates the component fine but the cli messes up my app.module.ts:

```
import { Component1Component } from './component1.componen;
import { Component2Component } from './component2.component't';
```

It removes the last "t" of the previous component and add a "'t" on the new one??
Has anyone else seen this?

EDIT.
Below is my package.json file BEFORE the upgrade to Angular cli 1.4.3

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.3",
    "@types/quill": "0.0.29",
    "angular2-csv": "^0.2.1",
    "angular2-json2csv": "^1.1.2",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.3.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.6.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "mydatepicker": "^1.9.11",
    "primeng": "^4.0.3",
    "quill": "^1.2.6",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.47",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.13",
    "angular": "^1.6.5",
    "codelyzer": "^3.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.0.0",
    "karma": "^1.6.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^4.2.1",
    "protractor": "^5.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^3.0.2",
    "tslint": "^5.1.0",
    "typescript": "^2.2.2"
  }
}
```

and here's my package.json after upgrading:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/quill": "0.0.29",
    "angular2-csv": "^0.2.1",
    "angular2-json2csv": "^1.1.2",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.3.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.6.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "mydatepicker": "^1.9.11",
    "primeng": "^4.0.3",
    "quill": "^1.2.6",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.47",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.13",
    "angular": "^1.6.5",
    "codelyzer": "^3.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.0.0",
    "karma": "^1.6.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^4.2.1",
    "protractor": "^5.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^3.0.2",
    "tslint": "^5.1.0",
    "typescript": "^2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: what is your node version? What happens if you try to reproduce an issue by creating a new app `ng new my-app`? Did you try cli `1.4.4`?

Comment: @Kuncevic I just upgraded to node 8 (I'm on Windows 10) but still get same issue. It doesn't happen if I start a new project with the latest angular cli but it would get far too complicated making a brand new one and merging everything over :(